# Replace latch on Frigidaire FFCD2413US4A dishwasher?

Tags: dishwasher

The latch of my Frigidaire FFCD2413US4A dishwasher was smashed by the previous owner, so the door won’t close. I got a replacement but the instructions say to (I believe cut and) re-wire the connector back together, which I don’t want to do unless I have to. The original connector came out without a problem since the latch was broken,

[image: original connector]
[image: broken latch with connector removed]

but now I want to remove the replacement connector (the white part of the new latch), but it won’t come out easily. I can get it loose from the plastic clips on the sides but I can’t get it all the way out because it’s firmly in at the bottom. It has something that looks like a release clip but for the life of me I can't get it at the right angle to get it out. Should I be able to remove this white part by hand? Or is my only option to cut and re-wire it in?

[image: replacement latch with white connector I'm having trouble removing]

Comment: Those wires should just pull out of the old connector and push in to the new one, no cutting necessary.  Breaking the lock on the new connector might be bad.

Comment: From 10,000 feet it looks like a snap in. Gently push the white lips outward, that are extending over the black part, there is a small pin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure it would be better to just swap the spade connectors rather than fight a plastic clip you can't see/reach properly. If you break the old plug getting them out, it's no biggie. Break the new one & it is.

Those blue covered spade connectors might put up a bit of a fight, but they will come out. There's often a little [theoretically one-way] tag in the middle which drops into a hole in the male end. Brute force can overcome it, so long as you're careful not to damage anything important.

Long-nosed pliers, either side of where the spade transitions to a cylinder is your best grip point. Wiggle, pull, lever against the plug edge… eventually it will give. They will be much easier to put back on the new one, the tag won't fight you that way.

[image]

Mark them first with a Sharpie so you know what order they go in.

I'm sure somewhere there exists a tool to do this - but it would mean you would need to strip & replace the heat-shrink insulation, so not really worth it.

Comment: The key is making sure you get them back in to the correct positions in the new connector. Hate to get 2 in swapped positions and have to go through the fight again to get them out & swap them back again...

Comment: @FreeMan - hence the sharpie, yup ;))